# My Egyptian E-Visa says that it is ‘valid until’ the day before I leave Egypt

Tags: egypt, e-visas

My Egyptian E-Visa says that it is valid until 2018-10-25, which is the day before I will leave Egypt. Does this date refer to entry only, or does it, as I fear it may, refer to departure as well?

EDIT:

More info:

- It’s a single entry tourism visa.
- I completed the application process by using the ‘family’ application type.

Comment: I can find no reference that suggests that you can stay beyond the validity of your visa (i.e. arriving on, say, day 80 of your visa validity and staying for more than 10 days is likely to be a problem). I did find a reference saying that the dates on an e-visa can't be changed once it is issued.  I'd play it safe and apply for a new e-visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve now got a response, and was reassured that the “valid until” date refers to entry only, and not exit. You can stay in Egypt for 30 days on this visa.

Comment: Do you have a reference for what you're "pretty sure" of? Without that this is just supposition and doesn't get the OP any further forward.

Comment: I’m the OP. I’ve emailed the e-visa agency to get some answers. I’ll report back when I get a response